# Upload Database file from ios to AWS s3 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ios8.1

Hi i try to upload a file to my bucket at AWS s3 without successes.

I just need to upload a file from some application from some phones.

i use AWS SDK version2 on ios 8.

this is my function for Upload a DB:

**UPLOAD**

```
 NSString *fileName = DB_File;
        NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];





    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    uploadRequest.key = fileName;
    uploadRequest.bucket = @"xxxx";

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                switch (task.error.code) {
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                    {
                     NSLog(@"Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
                    }
                        break;

                    default:
                        NSLog(@"Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
            }
        }

        if (task.result) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Upload ok: [%@]", task.error);
            });
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

**AppDelege.m**

**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                                                          credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionxxxx
                                                          identityPoolId:@"us-xxxx-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx"];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;


    return YES;
}
```

**

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated your bucket policy?

Comment: No, 
I new with amazon, what is need to be added there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your bucket policy to this (replace bucketName):

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "allow-public-read",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "allow-public-put",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*"
    }
]
}
```

This allows you to Add/Read objects from your bucket, you should read [AWS S3 Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) in order to know what exactly you want your policy to be, but for now, this should do the trick.

Comment: Still does not upload , maybe something else?

Comment: there is no errors.
The uploadRequest.key = "filename" is ok?

I have just opened a bucket without any internal folders. It is ok?

Comment: i find an error AWSRegion is not valid for bucket , thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I give up on using `AWS SDK`. I have tried with `AFAmazonS3Manager` and It works well.

[AFAmazonS3Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Manager): AFNetworking Client for the Amazon S3 API.